# Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Input-Group with TextBox & Button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, glyphicons

So I have a textbox and button set up exactly like this: http://www.bootply.com/78014 except im using @HTML.TextboxFor() instead of the  tag.

But I want to add a glyphicon on the textbox as well like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrnnkFR3Yv9HGQHrRMiW?p=preview or this: http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Ek/1/

Here is my actual code:

```
<div class="input-group col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-7 has-feedback" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Temp, new { @class = "form-control has-feedback", @placeholder = "If Known" })
<i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i>
<span class="input-group-btn">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Look Up", "Lookup", "NewUserRequest", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default", id = "lookupGuest" })
</span>
</div>
```

But what the glyphicon ends up being hidden under the button.

Comment: Try tagging this question as ASP.Net and MVC

Comment: Could you show the rendered html (source code in browser) ? it seem there is something wrong with your tag nesting (and as BS use it to apply CSS, it's probably the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by manually setting wraping the glyphicon in a  and manually the style of the glpyhicon *right*.

here is it working: https://jsfiddle.net/kuxxm9fb/

and here is the code itself:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
</br>
<div class="input-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess4"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok" id="extGuestGlyphiconOK" style="right: 45px"></span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
         <a class="btn btn-default" id="lookupGuest" href="#">link</a>
    </span>
</div>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand what you want... But, **Bootstrap don't allow you to do this**. You can't have a feedback gylph and a `group-btn` on the same input like you want. (It's about relative positioning in CSS, and I think you don't want to start patching the BootStrap CSS...)

This is what you can do, more or less : http://jsfiddle.net/LS2Ek/268/